# Looping a javascript promise to append to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, promise

Good day, below I have

```
    var request = require('request');
    getFood = function(lst){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            //console.log(lst)
            request('https://api.jamesoff.net/recipe', function (error, response, recipe) {
                lst.push(JSON.parse(recipe))
                resolve(lst);
            })
        });
    }   


    getFood([]).then(function(data){
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            getFood(data)
        }
        return(data);
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    })
```

What I am aiming to accomplish is by using a promise chain place three recipies into an array using a loop. I only get one item and I know why this occurs, however I can't wrap my head around the procedure to accomplish my goal. Could I please get an explanation with code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your getFood call in a loop.  If you are looping through promises the best way to do it is with `Promise.all()`

An example:

```
var promiseArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    promiseArray.push(getFood(data))
}
Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function(values) {
    // values is array of resolve values in the order that promises were pushed into the array
});
```

This resolves the promises in the order in which they were called and should help with your issues.

Comment: Ok so the key was placing the promises into an array first then running them at the same time.. with promise.all() which I didn't know about.. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  A general rule of thumb that I've found is that if you are using promises in a loop, you need to use Promise.all()